# Trouble getting a data connection on a Telit LEU910C1-EU modem

Tags: linux, networking, modem, networkmanager

I'm trying to connect a Telit LEU910C1-EU modem to get a data connection (over
LTE).  The module is used via a CM3, the modem itself is plugged into a usb
hub.  While tinkering around I got the following weird behavior:

- On a Ubuntu Laptop, I can use the modem just fine with ModemManager and NetworkManager.
  (see below for exact steps)
- On the Pi though I seem to get no errors and NetworkManager tells me I'm connected.
  When doing a `ping -I wwan0 8.8.8.8` though it blocks indefinitely.

I already tried many different SIMs (including the one in my smartphone) and
even swapped the modem. One weird thing is also that the whole Pi seems to be
unresponsive for a few seconds after starting the ModemManager and sometimes
the ethernet doesn't seem to be working anymore after.

I tried to summarize all important logs in this Gist:

https://gist.github.com/sahib/3a2d7951aec59ffd23f3d1eef60cc450

(This include all relevant software version, they are the same as on on the
Ubuntu laptop, except the kernel).

Those are the steps I use to setup the modem itself:

```
$ sudo systemctl start ModemManager
$ sudo systemctl start NetworkManager
# Check if the modem was recognized:
$ mmcli -L
# Check the status of the modem, if it shows "registered", continue.
$ mmcli -m 0
# Actually add the connection:
$ sudo nmcli c add type gsm ifname cdc-wdm0 con-name telit apn bicsapn
# Test the connction. This will block forever or yield "not reachable"
$ ping -I 8.8.8.8
```

Did anyone have similar issues or can help debug that further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

There are two things to check:

- `systemd-networkd` seems to interfere with NetworkManager. Disable it by using:

  `$ systemctl disable systemd-networkd` (reboot after)
- The MTU size was wrong. For LTE the maximum size seems to be around 1430. See `mmcli -b $(number of your bearer from mmcli -m 0).`. Lower it via `ip link set dev wwan0 mtu 1400`. It should work automatically after.

Answer (score 1):

In newer releases NetworkManager will take over the MTU size from ModemManager automatically: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/merge_requests/499

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.